# Adding new dask column based on a vectorized function

Tags: python, numpy, dask

I have what I thought would be a straightforward thing to do in python using dask. I have a dataframe with some records in it, and I want to add a new column based on calling a function with values from two other columns as parameters.

Here is what I mean (pretend `ge` exists and takes two parameters):

```
def gc(x, y):
    return ge(x, y)

def gdf(df):
    func1 = np.vectorize(gc)
    gh = da.from_array(func1(df.x, df.y))
    df['gh'] = gh
```

However, I seem to get one issue or another no matter what I try to do. Currently, in the above state, I get

```
Number of partitions do not match (2 != 33)
```

It feels like I'm either going about this all wrong (like maybe I need `map_blocks` or `map_partitions` or even `gufunc`), or I'm missing something easy where I can set the number of partitions on my array to match that of my dataframe.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to do this with `assign` or `map_partitions`:

```py
func1 = np.vectorize(gc)
df = df.assign(gh=lambda df: func1(df.x, df.y))

# or try this
def myfunc(df):
    df['gh'] = func1(df.x, df.y)
    return df

df = df.map_partitions(myfunc)
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid assign() since it's not so very performant. However, I seem to be experiencing success with the map_partitions approach. I'm going to test a bit more before accepting the answer. But, as of this very moment, you may be the hero we all needed :)

Comment: And success seems to be achieved. I did not use, or even try, the assign() approach. But, the map_partitions answered the mail very nicely.